# Whats wrong with DateTime object

Tags: php, datetime, date

Can anyone tell what is wrong with the code.

```
$timezone = "Asia/Karachi"; 
$date = new DateTime($when_to_send, new DateTimeZone($timezone));
$date = $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT')); 
$when_to_send = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

error is: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$date = $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT'));`

Makes the $date variable null, you should just call it:

`$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT'));`

Comment: waoo awesome it also solve my problem . Thank you soooo much

Answer (score 6):

If you're not running at least PHP 5.3.0 (as written in [the manual](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php), which you surely read before asking, right?), `setTimezone` will return NULL instead of the modified DateTime. Are you running at least PHP 5.3.0?

Comment: it gotto be less than 5.3 because removing assigment solved the issue

Comment: You can get your version by typing `php -v` from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php), `setTimeZone` will return either a `DateTime` object or a `FALSE` if it can't set the timezone. Saving the return is actually unnecessary because it will modify the `DateTime` object you pass it.

Perhaps you should check whether `setTimezone` succeeded before setting your `$date` object to its return value:

```
$timezone = "Asia/Karachi";
$date = new DateTime($when_to_send, new DateTimeZone($timezone));

if (! ($date && $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT'))) ) {
    # unable to adjust from local timezone to GMT!
    # (display a warning)
}

$when_to_send = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone who helped but only can be marked correct answer. Correct code is

```
$timezone = "Asia/Karachi"; 
$date = new DateTime($when_to_send, new DateTimeZone($timezone));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT')); 
$when_to_send = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```